# How to Connect three PCs via WiFi and USB tethering found in android

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, usb, android

I have two laptops with built-in WiFi and a desktop PC (running Windows 7) with no built-in WiFi and I have to connect three of these devices over network. I can connect the two laptops by creating a WiFi hotspot on my android phone. Since my PC doesn't have a WiFi hardware I can't connect to the WiFi network I created through hotspot. So I decided to connect my phone to the PC via USB tethering. I can access the internet but not my other two laptops from my PC (network file sharing is not working)

The two laptop are on the same network but my PC is on a separate network. I can't share printers and files with my PC

This is what I'm saying [the PC and Laptop are on different subnets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBgFa.png)

Is it possible to join the USB network with my WiFi network

How can I connect these devices without buying any extra hardwares?

Comment: Tether to the PC without internet (via USB) and enable hotspot to connect the 2 PCs with wireless cards.

Comment: That's what I did, the desktop PC with no WiFi adapter has an IP : (192.168.42.x) and the laptops with WiFi adapters have IPs : (192.168.43.x). That's why I can't connect them. What should I do?